# Catch and upload files from POST call

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.6

I am working in a REST Api and I am sending (uploading) a file in a `POST`. I am working with Symfony 2.6.8 and FOSRestBundle and I am doing this is on the method:

```
/**
 * Set and upload avatar for reps.
 *
 * @param ParamFetcher $paramFetcher
 * @param Request $request
 *
 * @ApiDoc(
 *      resource = true,
 *      https = true,
 *      description = "Set and upload avatar for reps.",
 *      statusCodes = {
 *          200 = "Returned when successful",
 *          400 = "Returned when errors"
 *      }
 * )
 *
 * @RequestParam(name="rid", nullable=false, strict=true, requirements="\d+", description="The ID of the representative")
 * @RequestParam(name="avatar", nullable=false, description="The avatar file")
 *
 * @return View
 */
public function postRepsAvatarAction(ParamFetcher $paramFetcher, Request $request)
{
    $view = View::create();
    $content = $request->getContent();

    print_r($content);
    $view->setData(array())->setStatusCode(200);

    return $view;
}
```

And this is what I am getting as response:

```
------WebKitFormBoundary3JCHTJWwvnOcvnSv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_format"

json
------WebKitFormBoundary3JCHTJWwvnOcvnSv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rid"

1
------WebKitFormBoundary3JCHTJWwvnOcvnSv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="avatar"; filename="carlingford.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

/* Here goes a lot of code that I suppose is image or so in base64 - below is just a example*/

���p��  
��T!1"AQa2q�#B��    R�$3b�C���%r�4S�&�5c
Ds��'ET�d6U���  ��L!1AQaq"��2����#��BR�b$3r����C%4S��s�&5DTc���?�g������F΅%v9��Ge�9�С@#B�'�y�4!p|hPW%<�8�:n��9�hI�B;�Ж�:R{�8Ћ(�m�:m�*����0��vƄ#��?'B���BQ����BGo}
;#�a#�΄U��W�x?�E��H��:��#Ռ�t�L�6C�u ��#�R����22����n�c���B�@3ƅ"��ZRN�dv΄�����Д��pB��'B]�rҥ�����Q���)P�� �R�����R9Y�I&���    =���X?�bI�u��ĮQ���!C�'dn�}��-n�s�j8  �c$����Q����$�q��� �@�J9$ryԁj�pN�9���B8+*��v�Sih�J}[�W��ґ���R�r�?��h�I�J!�P�?J��+��T���+��Q�)�m
od
```

How do I catch that POST file and create a file for upload to server through Symfony? Can any give me ideas or sample code?

**EDIT1:**

Since I am using `FOSRestBundle` and `NelmioApiDocBundle` I am using Nelmio Sandbox mode as shown in the image below:

[image]

Comment: Check `$request->files`

Comment: You should be able to take the contents,  remove the headers,  and write to a file

Comment: @pcnate this is what I am trying to do but I can't so I need some help from someone here to show me some code and I take it as a guide to follow, really I am stucked and don't know how to move forward

Comment: I'd write a regex to strip the headers you have from `$content`. Or is that not the results of the print_r?

Comment: @pcnate this is not the whole response but yes, all that is what I get if I do a `print_r($request->getContent())`

Comment: @zerkms how that help me? I mean that should be a ParameterBag for $_FILES but from there I don't know where to go, any code to show and point me in the right direction?

Comment: @ReynierPM it's an object of `FileBag` type which has all what you need. It's not clear what actually makes you stuck.

Comment: @zerkms for example see my edit, I did a test and get nothing in the output. What makes me get stucked is how to create a file from the POST content and upload to the server

Comment: Show the HTML for the form that sends the request (if there is a form), or a corresponding client code that sends data to your API.

Comment: @zerkms I haven't I am using NelmioApiDoc Sandbox mode to try the API but I has updated the post with info around the API

Comment: So where exactly `"carlingford.jpg"` file comes from?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79081/discussion-between-reynierpm-and-zerkms).

Comment: A RESTful api should be using PUT instead of POST for uploads

Comment: @Anthony that's not true. Uploading a file is no different from creating any other resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use regex to break out what you have printed:

```
$re = "/(?P<headers>.*)[\\r\\n][\\r\\n](?P<content>.*)/mis";

preg_match_all ( $re, $request->getContent(), $matches );

print_r( $matches );
```

You should be able to take the matched element from `$matches` and use `file_put_contents` or equivalent.

Example: https://regex101.com/r/oW6fM4/1